# Getting browser error from SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

We have a server which is showing this message on all browsers with different format.

> There is problem with this website's security certificate

Screenshot:

[image]

I have already checked the Time on the Server machine and client and they are both up to date and correct. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update your system **date**. Wrong date is making such issue. Correct your system date and click on the "Connect to this website(not recommended)". PLease, check. Thanks

Comment: If you read the error message carefully, you would notice that the problem is not related to date/time.

Comment: It is accepted by Mona but came here to beat about the bushes and down voting. :D

Comment: For whatever reason OP accepted your answer, it is not the solution, because certificate's chain is untrusted and is issued to wrong server name.

Comment: You may know that CA (certified authorities) issues certificates for specific dates or for some duration but her system date is behind the certificate date so it was creating such issue. Don't make things more complex. Please, have a look on SSL/TLS.

Comment: When certificate is time invalid, IE will explicitly say that certificate is expired (or not yet valid): http://media.askvg.com/articles/images5/Certificate_Error_Internet%20_Explorer.png Again, as per OP post, date and time is up to date.

Comment: I don't wanted to bang my head to wall. Just chill and enjoy. FYI, she has accepted the answer because her problem is solved. BTW, i don't know her dude. enjoy